# Getting the index of the value passed in

Tags: java

```
public static int getIndex(String value, Constants type) {
    int myPosition = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < type.length; i++) {
        if (type[i] == value) {
            myPosition = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return myPosition;
}
```

I was thinking of a generic method where i pass the value and Constants into the method to get the required index of the string value. Its pretty much easy to do in `JS`, but i am not sure how can i toss a method of same in java.

```
CommonMethods.Utils.getIndex("Kevin", Contants.Name);
```

The above method is not working, as it says **"length cannot be resolved or is not a field"**

Comment: What is `Constants`?  An enum?  An interface?  A class?  The attribute `length` is valid on arrays (and when `length` is explicitly declared on a class or interface).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: What *should* the code do?

Answer (score 3):

Your `Constants` object should be some sort of `Collection`. Look those up. There's a lot of them with different attributes.

What you seem to be rewriting here is a [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Those already have a function to search inside called `indexOf`.

Comment: How do i get the index of my object which is actually mapped to my Array... lets take my array contains three objects ["sas","asas","asas"]. ArrayList.indexOf(myObject) would return me the index of the Array items or index of the List.

Answer (score 1):

`type` is a `Constants`, not an array. You can't run `type.length` because `Constants` does not define a `length` property.

If `Constants` is an enum you can use `Constants.values()` to get an array of all constants.